# React Material UI Dialog opening causes design problems

Tags: reactjs, firebase, material-ui

I made a React app which is working fine. I've used many components from Material UI, such as Card, Paper, Typography, etc.

Recently, out of nowhere, I'm experiencing very strange behaviour when I open certain dialogs. I've gone through all my code and for the life of me cannot figure out why.

The app is used to type in recipes which are saved for later viewing and management. Should be simple stuff.

### [1. Normal layout screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNy7P.png)

This is how the main screen is meant to look. Notice the blue app bar on top, the red hearted icons, grey sharing icons, and normal looking cards with everything properly aligned.

### [2. View recipe dialog screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCjBW.png)

When clicking a card to open the recipe, it opens a dialog box, and it causes very strange behaviour. The close X button used to be on the top right corner of the dialog, but now it's right near the title and misaligned. And in the background, the bar on the top of the screen has lost its blue colour, and the card layouts have become all strange. Additionally, the hearted icons and sharing icons are now black.

### [3. Add recipe dialog screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxmZK.png)

When adding a new recipe, some of the same strange behaviour appears in the background with the wonky card layouts and icon colours. The app bar colour stays, but still some of the elements within in jump around slightly. And in the dialog itself, the "meal type" button group, which should be the Material UI outlined variant, is all squished together.

-------------

I must reiterate that it didn't use to be this way. Somewhere in the thousands of edits I've made to everything, this behaviour introduced itself and hasn't gone away over a few weeks.

**Has anyone experienced this behaviour or have any inkling of how to get rid of it?**

GitHub repo: https://github.com/yhavin/grandma (Recipes page component, RecipeForm component, RecipeCard component)

Comment: Hi are you using 2 UI package ? one of these can overwrite rules from another ui

Comment: @Jud3v No, I'm just using Material UI.